# Objects in same container row are appearing under each other

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row of bike images with the manufacturer name that are appearing on top of each other. See screenshot for reference. I'm using "col-md-12" so shouldn't it be horizontal instead of vertical since I used all 12 grid columns?
How can I get each image to appear next to each other instead.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='formApp'>

<head>
    <title>Bicycle App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class='row'>

                <div class='col-md-12'>

                    <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"><span>&nbsp;{{"Andy's Bike Shop"}}</span></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">


        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                <!-- end class not needed -->
                <div class="chooseTitle">
                    Choose Your Bicycle
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <!-- you missed md from offset, end class not needed -->
                <div class="products" ng-controller="BikeController">
                  <div ng-repeat="product in products">
                  {{product.manufacturer}}
                  <br>
                  <img id="bikePic" ng-src="{{product.image}}">
                  </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>



    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
    var app = angular.module('formApp', []);
app.controller('BikeController',['$scope', function($scope){

$scope.products = [
{
manufacturer: "Trek",
image: 'images/bike1.jpg'
}, 
{
manufacturer: "Mongoose",
image: 'images/bike2.jpg'

},
{

    manufacturer: "Portlandia",
image: 'images/bike3.jpg'
},
{

    manufacturer: "Giant",
image: 'images/bike4.jpg'
},
{

    manufacturer: "Framed",
image: 'images/bike5.jpg'
}
];


this.form = {};
this.addForm = function(product){

};

}]);
```

app.css

```
.header{
    font-style:italic;
background-color:black;
height:60px;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:40px;
position:relative;
padding-top:10px;
padding-left:16px;
margin-left:-10px;
 margin-right:-10px;
margin-top:-10px;

}
.header .fa {font-style:italic;
}
.bikeSelector{
color:green;
}
.chooseTitle{

font-size:60px;

}

.products{
color:red;

font-size:60px;

}
#bikePic{

height:20%;
width:20%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `col-md-12` you're using for each image is telling the DIV to span across 12 columns, which is the max number of columns you can have per row.

Instead, use a smaller number of columns per div to make a maximum of 12,

e.g.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">img</div>
<div class="col-md-4">img</div>
<div class="col-md-4">img</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">img</div>
<div class="col-md-2">img</div>
<div class="col-md-2">img</div>
<div class="col-md-2">img</div>
<div class="col-md-2">img</div>
<div class="col-md-2">img</div>
</div>
```

As you can see - all of the div's collectively add up to 12 - which is a row's width.

Comment: I'm also using angularjs so how can I apply that while using ng-repeat to output content? I'm cycling through the images like this  <div ng-repeat="product in products">
                  {{product.manufacturer}}
                  <br>
                  <img id="bikePic" ng-src="{{product.image}}">
                  </div>

Comment: Just add a class to the div. `<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="product in products">`

Answer (score 0):

`col-md-12` means that that column is 12 segments wide.  Bootstrap's `container` is 12 segments wide, so your column is full width, thus will stack vertically.

See documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic).

- If you want 3 columns then use `col-md-4` ... (12 / 3 = 4)
- If you want 4 columns then use `col-md-3` ... (12 / 4 = 3)
- If you want 6 columns then use `col-md-2` ... (12 / 6 = 2) *... etc.*